# Restrict Android Library To Be Used Only By Host Application Packages

Tags: java, android

I am working on a SDK project for Android and there is a requirement which wants us to restrict the usage of this SDK (aar) to only the host application packages.

**For example**

- Our SDK/library namespace - `com.abc.sdk`
- Target App namespace -`com.xyz.app`
- Malicious SDK/library namespace - `com.mal.sdk`

Is there a way we can restrict the `com.abc.sdk` invocation to only `com.xyz.app.*` so no classes in malicious SDK/library can invoke our SDK/library.

Comment: If this is truly an SDK (something to be distributed to arbitrary developers), then how are you expecting to know what the target app namespace is?

Comment: This library would be provided to few app owners and would not be available to arbitrary owners.

Comment: That does not answer my question. How are you expecting to know what the target app namespace is?

Comment: @CommonsWare I was watching this question, and happy to see you came here. There is one implementation for support libraries where we get error when we use some classes or resources. I did not remember the error but it is like "you can not use this class from different library group". I am curious to know that. Could you please share any link which can help to understand that implementation?

Comment: @PankajKumar: I assume you are referring to [`@RestrictTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RestrictTo). That is just a warning, though -- apps can still use the "restricted" items.

Comment: @CommonsWare the target application can be available to us during the on-boarding. Where we can generate a client specific aar library. Since the client can have other dependencies also included in their app, we don't want other libraries to access our functionalities directly. Hope this clarifies the question and thanks for the help.